# How to store every output from a for loop in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I cant figure out how to get all of the output values into my dict. When I run my code I only get last output, but if I use print inside the for loop to test I can see that I am collecting more outputs.

My goal is to get all of the outputs and not only the last.

**CODE:**

```
def cointelegraph():
    for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='post-preview-item-inline'):
        content = dict()
        title = div.find(class_='post-preview-item-inline__title').get_text()
        #print(title)
        content['title'] = title
        body = div.find(class_='post-preview-item-inline__text').get_text()
        #print(body)
        content['body'] = body
        for links in div.select('.post-preview-item-inline__figure-link'):
            link = links.get('href')
            #print(link)
            content['link'] = link
            content['total_body'] = body + '\n \n' +' Link to article: ' + link

    return content


#make_post(cointelegraph())
print(cointelegraph())
```

**RESULT:**

```
{'title': ' Bitcoin Price Reclaims $10K Reversing Weekend Losses, XTZ Soars 13% ', 'body': ' Bitcoin price briefly reclaimed $10K after a bearish weekend which saw the creation of a new CME gap at $10,460. ', 'link': 'https://cointelegraph.com/news/bitcoin-price-reclaims-10k-reversing-weekend-losses-xtz-soars-13', 'total_body': ' Bitcoin price briefly reclaimed $10K after a bearish weekend which saw the creation of a new CME gap at $10,460. \n \n Link to article: https://cointelegraph.com/news/bitcoin-price-reclaims-10k-reversing-weekend-losses-xtz-soars-13'}
```

[image: Source HTML]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a wrong data structure and at wrong place. Try something like below

```
def cointelegraph():
    all_content = []

    for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='post-preview-item-inline'):
        content = dict()
        title = div.find(class_='post-preview-item-inline__title').get_text()
        #print(title)
        content['title'] = title
        body = div.find(class_='post-preview-item-inline__text').get_text()
        #print(body)
        content['body'] = body
        content['links'] = []
        for links in div.select('.post-preview-item-inline__figure-link'):
            link = links.get('href')
            #print(link)
            content['links'].append({"link": link, 'total_body': body + '\n \n' +' Link to article: ' + link})

        all_content.append(content)
    return all_content
```